# exclude items from array through loop c#

Tags: c#, loops, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to remove items from array to filter out items if it contains some certain words, i'm getting out of bounds exception and i ran out of ideas how to resolve it... please help!

```
string[] files = {
                "image4.png",
                "copy.psd",
                "image3.jpg",
                "image1.png",
                "image2.png",
            };
            string numToRemove = "";
            string[] namesArray = Console.ReadLine().Split(',');
            int num = 0;
            foreach(string t in files){
                Console.WriteLine(t);
                foreach(string s in namesArray){ 
                    if(files[num].Contains(s)){
                        numToRemove = s;
                        Console.WriteLine("exist");
                        files = files.Where(val => val != numToRemove).ToArray();
                    }
                }
                num++;
            };
```

edit:
Thanks to everyone for your quick answers and solutions

Comment: Can't you use a list? It's gonna make your life much easier, any case, there plenty of array operations which could help you: https://www.dotnetperls.com/array-resize

Comment: Re-assigning the `files` array while in a foreach on the `files` array is a terrible plan sure to blow up in your face. The normal procedure if you want to delete sans-LINQ is to iterate (normal `for` loop) backwards so you can delete and not mess up your indices going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not the linq  .ToArray() call, but instead, the foreach() cycle of the files list.  When the loop starts, it is initializing the internal counter to the ORIGINAL size of the files array (5) in this case.  As you go through and successfully find a match in the files array, you are dynamically re-sizing it down to 4.  So now, the loop is still cycling through all 5 original count which is where you get your crash.

Instead, loop the files loop by for() with a counter starting with the highest length and working back.  So, if you find a match on item #3 in the list, your next cycle will be 2 after you resize the files array.  a valid index #2 will still exist as you work down to zero.

Another thing I ran into was a test where someone puts spaces after each comma.  Your array (as in this example where I hard-coded a string) will create your strings such as

```
namesArray[0] = "copy.psd"
namesArray[1] = " more"
namesArray[2] = " test"
namesArray[3] = " image4.png"
```

Notice the leading spaces of the strings from the split?  This would give a false negative and skip (in this example) image4.png from being removed.

I have updated a function to show a working instance of what you are attempting and also pre-trimming the strings after they have been "split()".

```
    private void testArray()
    {
        string[] files = {
            "image4.png",
            "copy.psd",
            "image3.jpg",
            "image1.png",
            "image2.png",
        };

        string[] namesArray = "copy.psd, more, test, image4.png".Split(',');
        // pre-trim each string for proper test when comparing strings in arrays
        for (var na = 0; na < namesArray.Length; na++)
            namesArray[na] = namesArray[na].Trim();


        // Now, look for each files to the namesArray
        for ( var outerNum = files.Length -1; outerNum >= 0; outerNum-- )
        {
            var curFileName = files[outerNum];
            Console.WriteLine(curFileName);

            if( namesArray.Contains(curFileName))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(curFileName + " exist");
                files = files.Where(val => val != curFileName).ToArray();
            }
        };

        Console.Write(files.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: I did my best to give an alternative alternative answer. I think yours solves the immediate problem the OP has, but it has a for loop, within the for loop it uses a Contains, Where + ToArray. I get that the original code had a similar setup, I just think the code as is not easily readable, it's a bit to verbose. The framework offers a method to do exactly that, and if he needs it to be an array, he can do ToArray on the result. If he wants to know which files are in both lists, he can use [Intersect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: thank you for your answer, this does  help me understand why it didnt worked, but i still need to exclude all items if that contain certain extension for example. I didnt mention that in post, but thank you for the answer again.

Comment: @user78430, this DOES remove those in the list and leaves the resulting files array reduced.  I was just starting at the END of the list working to the front to correct the issue of your index out of range.  Still did the same result.

Comment: @user78430, same context would apply.  Except the "Contains( curFileName)" portion, you might want to apply a  Path.GetExtension( curFileName ) == the fileNames array element you are working on.  Ex: you want to exclude all ".pdf", ".png", etc..  Hopefully this comment can help you out.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
files = files.Except(namesArray).ToArray();
```

Namespace require: `System.Linq;`

Comment: Although an alternative to their linq attempt, does not resolve the issue of the index out of range on subsequent looping.

Comment: @DRapp, but it removes the need for the full code that the OP posted (except maybe for the `Trim` you added in your answer)

Answer (score 1):

To be fair, both answerers give a good input to your original question. Where [DRapp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64429513/3231537) gives you an idea why it happens, [Tân](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64429012/3231537) gives you an alternative solution.

I think both solutions have their merit, but I don't see why you would want to have a for loop and a recreation of the same array over and over again as in the example of DRapp.

Say that you don't know about the alternative that Tân described in his answer, probably the easiest way forward in your code would be to extract the functionality and generalize it so it is flexible (and reusable, but that's not really the point).

To do that, you just create a new method that returns you a `IEnumerable<string>` as a result.

Say you extract the code that removes existing entries from your set of data, you could write something like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetWithout(IEnumerable<string> entries, IEnumerable<string> toExclude) {
    var excludeSet = new HashSet<string>( toExclude, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase );
    foreach (var entry in entries) {
        if (excludeSet.Contains( entry )) {
            continue;
        }
        yield return entry;
    }
}
```

And you could then call this code at a later point in time, like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var files = new string[] {
            "image4.png",
            "copy.psd",
            "image3.jpg",
            "image1.png",
            "image2.png",
        };
    var input = "copy.psd, more, test, Image4.png";
    
    var filesWithoutInput = GetWithout( files, input.Split(',').Select( item => item.Trim() ) );
    Console.WriteLine( string.Join(", ", filesWithoutInput ) );
}
```

I find the code that Tân provides the easiest to read, it's succinct and supports a different `IEqualityComparer` as a second argument. It's also part of the framework, and is an extension method, you can basically use it for all types, and provided you add the `System.Linq` namespace to your usings you can use it from anywhere.

The code I shared above doesn't have that, and it doesn't let you choose the comparer, so it's less flexible. If you would like case sensitive comparison, you would have to change the code. If you want to reuse the code at another place, you would have the same problem.

You could of course rewrite it like the following

```
internal static class EnumerableExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetWithout<T>(this IEnumerable<T> entries, IEnumerable<T> toExclude, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = default(IEqualityComparer<T>)) {
        var excludeSet = new HashSet<T>( toExclude, comparer );
        foreach (var entry in entries) {
            if (excludeSet.Contains( entry )) {
                continue;
            }
            yield return entry;
        }
    }
}
```

Which would have all the advantages of the [`System.Linq.Enumerable.Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except) method but in this case, I don't see why you would want to.

What you would have in my code sample, and in Tân's answer, is that you could get duplicate entries, if your `files` array contains more than one time the same name, but for that you could change it to `files.Distinct().GetWithout( namesArray )` or `files.Distinct().Except( namesArray )`

Comment: I commented from your question on my answer.  I do like yours though with the enumerable to just return what IS allowed.  Nice alternative.